# Border and Dropshadow

Tags: css

I need help modifying my style.css file. I want to add the boarder and drop shadow effect around both my main content container and my sidebar, found on my blog pages, to the main content container and sidebar on my main pages. Thank you!

Here is an example [blog page](https://www.shiftins.com/blog/boat-insurance-5-things-remember-want-perfect-policy/)

[image]

Here is an example [main page](https://www.shiftins.com/service/add-a-driver/)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to add some classes to the `<article>` and `<sidebar>` elements on the page you want to add the box shadow to so that it's more specific, but this should work:

```
.content, .sidebar{
    border: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
    border-bottom: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 .15em .35em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.135);
}
```

Those are the same values for the border and dropshadow found on your first example.

Comment: it's correct answer as i can see from inspect elements for your first example

Comment: Yeah I'm not really sure why I got downvoted. I specified that the OP should probably be more specific with the class names - OP didn't really expand on what they've tried or give code examples so my solution is a quick catch all that should hopefully lead them in the right direction.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't very specific but yes box-shadow: 0 0.15em 0.35em 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.135); is the code I was looking for. Can you help me identify what containers I need to add these to to get the desired effect on my main pages?

Comment: `.content` and `.sidebar` are two containers I can identify that would benefit from having the border and drop shadow, but it really depends on the aesthetic you're looking for.